# Convert 0x1234 to 0x11223344

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

How do I expand the hexadecimal number 0x1234 to 0x11223344 in a high-performance way?

```
unsigned int c = 0x1234, b;
b = (c & 0xff) << 4 | c & 0xf | (c & 0xff0) << 8
        | (c & 0xff00) << 12 | (c & 0xf000) << 16;
printf("%p -> %p\n", c, b);
```

Output:

```
0x1234 -> 0x11223344
```

I need this for color conversion. Users provide their data in the form 0xARGB, and I need to convert it to `0xAARRGGBB`. And yes, there could be millions, because each could be a pixel. 1000x1000 pixels equals to one million.

The actual case is even more complicated, because a single 32-bit value contains both foreground and background colors. So `0xARGBargb` become: `[ 0xAARRGGBB, 0xaarrggbb ]`

Oh yes, one more thing, in a real application I also negate alpha, because in [OpenGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL) 0xFF is non-transparent and 0x00 is most transparent, which is inconvenient in most cases, because usually you just need an `RGB` part and transparency is assumed to be non-present.

Comment: I disagree that this belongs on code review unless the scope of SO is radically changing. Questions about the most efficient way to perform operations like this have always been on-topic in the past.

Comment: What if I remove my code and only leave the question "how to convert 1234h to 11223344h in a high performance way"?

Comment: Might almost be a better question for the [Programming Puzzles and Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) discussion. (Oh, I see what you're doing. Yeah, ugly but works.)

Comment: @exebook _'What if I remove my code'_ No, I don't think this would be a good idea! Better try to point out your particular doubts you have with your code actually!

Comment: @keshlam it's not tricky at all, it's the most straight-forward way of going about it. Edit: and now the code itself has been removed from the question.

Comment: Actually, I think the answer to the original question was probably "no, there probably isn't a better way."

Comment: @keshlam there might be a way to do it in one step with multiplication.

Comment: @MarkRansom I was thinking about that, but evidence suggests the answer is "no". Or rather: Yes, but not that would work for any other input pattern.

Comment: @exebook I think it might work efficiently for the actual numbers you give! To generalize, make it a template or such ...

Comment: You shouldn't be using `%p` to print `unsigned int` values - use `%#x` to get hexadecimal output with leading `0x` from an `unsigned int`.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that unless you need this to run millions of times every second on some kind of real time software, the performance cost of your implementation will be close to nothing. Saving one or two &'s at a cost of readability is ridiculous when our code runs on processors that can do video effects in real time.

Comment: Another approach would be to use a lookup table (if you can spare 256kB)...

Comment: I know you don't have an SSE tag here. But it's probably worth noting you could do this sort of thing very quickly for a couple color values at once perhaps using no higher than SSE2 intrinsics. But not sure if you're interested in such a thing. Does your code run millions of times, every second perhaps, as Linuxios calls to attention?

Comment: @Rich It is actually not so simple to do using SIMD instructions, but it certainly could be vectorized.

Comment: @BЈовић After thinking about it some more I realized it's somewhat harder than I first thought, mostly because the values to be expanded are smaller than one byte. But there is a way around it using a shuffle operations and some masks. Time permitting, I'll try to post it as a solution.

Comment: I've now posted an SSE solution below. It uses SSE4, though it could be dumbed down to SSSE3 easily enough. As is, it uses 8 instructions, and operates on 4 color values at once. So it is about 2 instructions per color value.

Comment: So who's gonna write the performance test?

Comment: I KNOW this is faster than the original way. That is I've measured enough similar optimizations to be quite confident. I wouldn't be surprised if it were 10x faster or so, at the very least 6x on a reasonable i7. The lookup table method mentioned above would be interesting to measure as well, that ones a little more of a mystery to me as far as how it will perform. But I think it's going to lose a lot because it's going to overfill the L1 if not L2 cache.

Comment: Maybe I'll write a test if I find time, but I believe such a test should be one big loop with no calls that reads from one buffer and writes to another in order to be fair. That is if you read it to an x64 register and then have to transfer it to an xmm register, that will slow things down quite a bit. The test should load from memory directly into the registers to do the computation (and write from the same registers back to memory to store the result).

Comment: Performance requirement is bogus. You're already parsing the numbers first. Just adjust the parser.

Comment: @AShelly I wrote the performance test, see the edit to my answer if you're curious.

Comment: By the way, the alpha channel in OpenGL has no implicit meaning. Transparency is one use for it, but this behavior you discuss where `0xFF` is opaque and `0x00` is transparent is all a consequence of the alpha test and/or blending. You can easily make anything you want of the alpha channel in a shader, so you could avoid having to do any special-case processing on the CPU. Nevertheless, it is best you keep the alpha channel around anyway for data alignment purposes. 24-bit image formats are nasty.

Comment: Also, you are discussing OpenGL images here. Colors in OpenGL are generally fixed-point, such that a 4-bit color component maps to the range [**0**, **1**] (unorm) through `(1/15) * C`. Simply expanding the color components from 4- to 8-bit by repeating 4 of the bits is not going to produce the same color. The new fixed-point scale becomes (**1/255**). Are you using an integer color format rather than fixed-point?

Comment: As much as I love exploring perforance limits, both @Potatoswatter and Andon have good points. We may be optimizing the wrong solution.  First, the expansion is wrong. You wouldn't expand .1 to .11 if you needed extra decimal digits; you shouldn't do it that way for hex digits either.  But more importantly, where are you getting millions of ints per second in the wrong format?  Definitely not User input.  File IO? Store the expanded values instead.

Comment: I don't think the expansion is wrong - we're looking for the same fraction of the maximum representable value, not the same value, and duplicating the digit gives that.  As for just storing the expanded values to begin with, that may be the better option.. but there can be cases where that's not feasible (images streamed in from third party software, a camera, etc.).  So, store the expanded values to begin with *if possible*...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about optimizing working code; you may be able to get better help on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This can be done using [SSE2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE2) as follows:

```
void ExpandSSE2(unsigned __int64 in, unsigned __int64 &outLo, unsigned __int64 &outHi) {
  __m128i const mask = _mm_set1_epi16((short)0xF00F);
  __m128i const mul0 = _mm_set1_epi16(0x0011);
  __m128i const mul1 = _mm_set1_epi16(0x1000);
  __m128i       v;

  v = _mm_cvtsi64_si128(in); // Move the 64-bit value to a 128-bit register
  v = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(v, v);  // 0x12   -> 0x1212
  v = _mm_and_si128(v, mask);   // 0x1212 -> 0x1002
  v = _mm_mullo_epi16(v, mul0); // 0x1002 -> 0x1022
  v = _mm_mulhi_epu16(v, mul1); // 0x1022 -> 0x0102
  v = _mm_mullo_epi16(v, mul0); // 0x0102 -> 0x1122

  outLo = _mm_extract_epi64(v, 0);
  outHi = _mm_extract_epi64(v, 1);
}
```

Of course you’d want to put the guts of the function in an inner loop and pull out the constants. You will also want to skip the x64 registers and load values directly into 128-bit SSE registers. For an example of how to do this, refer to the SSE2 implementation in the performance test below.

At its core, there are five instructions, which perform the operation on four color values at a time. So, that is only about 1.25 instructions per color value. It should also be noted that SSE2 is available anywhere x64 is available.

**Performance tests for an assortment of the solutions here**
A few people have mentioned that the only way to know what's faster is to run the code, and this is unarguably true. So I've compiled a few of the solutions into a performance test so we can compare apples to apples. I chose solutions which I felt were significantly different from the others enough to require testing. All the solutions read from memory, operate on the data, and write back to memory. In practice some of the SSE solutions will require additional care around the alignment and handling cases when there aren't another full 16 bytes to process in the input data. The code I tested is x64 compiled under release using [Visual Studio 2013](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2013) running on a 4+ GHz [Core i7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core#Core_i7).

**Here are my results:**

```
ExpandOrig:               56.234 seconds  // From asker's original question
ExpandSmallLUT:           30.209 seconds  // From Dmitry's answer
ExpandLookupSmallOneLUT:  33.689 seconds  // from Dmitry's answer
ExpandLookupLarge:        51.312 seconds  // A straightforward lookup table
ExpandAShelly:            43.829 seconds  // From AShelly's answer
ExpandAShellyMulOp:       43.580 seconds  // AShelly's answer with an optimization
ExpandSSE4:               17.854 seconds  // My original SSE4 answer
ExpandSSE4Unroll:         17.405 seconds  // My original SSE4 answer with loop unrolling
ExpandSSE2:               17.281 seconds  // My current SSE2 answer
ExpandSSE2Unroll:         17.152 seconds  // My current SSE2 answer with loop unrolling
```

In the test results above you'll see I included the asker's code, three lookup table implementations including the small lookup table implementation proposed in Dmitry's answer. AShelly's solution is included too, as well as a version with an optimization I made (an operation can be eliminated). I included my original SSE4 implementation, as well as a superior SSE2 version I made later (now reflected as the answer), as well as unrolled versions of both since they were the fastest here, and I wanted to see how much unrolling sped them up. I also included an SSE4 implementation of AShelly's answer.

So far I have to declare myself the winner. But the source is below, so anyone can test it out on their platform, and include their own solution into the testing to see if they've made a solution that's even faster.

```
#define DATA_SIZE_IN  ((unsigned)(1024 * 1024 * 128))
#define DATA_SIZE_OUT ((unsigned)(2 * DATA_SIZE_IN))
#define RERUN_COUNT   500

#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <emmintrin.h> // SSE2
#include <tmmintrin.h> // SSSE3
#include <smmintrin.h> // SSE4

void ExpandOrig(unsigned char const *in, unsigned char const *past, unsigned char *out) {
  unsigned u, v;
  do {
    // Read in data
    u  = *(unsigned const*)in;
    v  = u >> 16;
    u &= 0x0000FFFF;

    // Do computation
    u  =   (u & 0x00FF) << 4
         | (u & 0x000F)
         | (u & 0x0FF0) << 8
         | (u & 0xFF00) << 12
         | (u & 0xF000) << 16;
    v  =   (v & 0x00FF) << 4
         | (v & 0x000F)
         | (v & 0x0FF0) << 8
         | (v & 0xFF00) << 12
         | (v & 0xF000) << 16;

    // Store data
    *(unsigned*)(out)      = u;
    *(unsigned*)(out + 4)  = v;
    in                    += 4;
    out                   += 8;
  } while (in != past);
}

unsigned LutLo[256],
         LutHi[256];
void MakeLutLo(void) {
  for (unsigned i = 0, x; i < 256; ++i) {
    x        = i;
    x        = ((x & 0xF0) << 4) | (x & 0x0F);
    x       |= (x << 4);
    LutLo[i] = x;
  }
}
void MakeLutHi(void) {
  for (unsigned i = 0, x; i < 256; ++i) {
    x        = i;
    x        = ((x & 0xF0) << 20) | ((x & 0x0F) << 16);
    x       |= (x << 4);
    LutHi[i] = x;
  }
}

void ExpandLookupSmall(unsigned char const *in, unsigned char const *past, unsigned char *out) {
  unsigned u, v;
  do {
    // Read in data
    u  = *(unsigned const*)in;
    v  = u >> 16;
    u &= 0x0000FFFF;

    // Do computation
    u = LutHi[u >> 8] | LutLo[u & 0xFF];
    v = LutHi[v >> 8] | LutLo[v & 0xFF];

    // Store data
    *(unsigned*)(out)      = u;
    *(unsigned*)(out + 4)  = v;
    in                    += 4;
    out                   += 8;
  } while (in != past);
}

void ExpandLookupSmallOneLUT(unsigned char const *in, unsigned char const *past, unsigned char *out) {
  unsigned u, v;
  do {
    // Read in data
    u = *(unsigned const*)in;
    v = u >> 16;
    u &= 0x0000FFFF;

    // Do computation
    u = ((LutLo[u >> 8] << 16) | LutLo[u & 0xFF]);
    v = ((LutLo[v >> 8] << 16) | LutLo[v & 0xFF]);

    // Store data
    *(unsigned*)(out) = u;
    *(unsigned*)(out + 4) = v;
    in  += 4;
    out += 8;
  } while (in != past);
}

unsigned LutLarge[256 * 256];
void MakeLutLarge(void) {
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < (256 * 256); ++i)
    LutLarge[i] = LutHi[i >> 8] | LutLo[i & 0xFF];
}

void ExpandLookupLarge(unsigned char const *in, unsigned char const *past, unsigned char *out) {
  unsigned u, v;
  do {
    // Read in data
    u  = *(unsigned const*)in;
    v  = u >> 16;
    u &= 0x0000FFFF;

    // Do computation
    u = LutLarge[u];
    v = LutLarge[v];

    // Store data
    *(unsigned*)(out)      = u;
    *(unsigned*)(out + 4)  = v;
    in                    += 4;
    out                   += 8;
  } while (in != past);
}

void ExpandAShelly(unsigned char const *in, unsigned char const *past, unsigned char *out) {
  unsigned u, v, w, x;
  do {
    // Read in data
    u  = *(unsigned const*)in;
    v  = u >> 16;
    u &= 0x0000FFFF;

    // Do computation
    w  = (((u & 0xF0F) * 0x101) & 0xF000F) + (((u & 0xF0F0) * 0x1010) & 0xF000F00);
    x  = (((v & 0xF0F) * 0x101) & 0xF000F) + (((v & 0xF0F0) * 0x1010) & 0xF000F00);
    w += w * 0x10;
    x += x * 0x10;

    // Store data
    *(unsigned*)(out)      = w;
    *(unsigned*)(out + 4)  = x;
    in                    += 4;
    out                   += 8;
  } while (in != past);
}

void ExpandAShellyMulOp(unsigned char const *in, unsigned char const *past, unsigned char *out) {
  unsigned u, v;
  do {
    // Read in data
    u = *(unsigned const*)in;
    v = u >> 16;
    u &= 0x0000FFFF;

    // Do computation
    u = ((((u & 0xF0F) * 0x101) & 0xF000F) + (((u & 0xF0F0) * 0x1010) & 0xF000F00)) * 0x11;
    v = ((((v & 0xF0F) * 0x101) & 0xF000F) + (((v & 0xF0F0) * 0x1010) & 0xF000F00)) * 0x11;

    // Store data
    *(unsigned*)(out) = u;
    *(unsigned*)(out + 4) = v;
    in += 4;
    out += 8;
  } while (in != past);
}

void ExpandSSE4(unsigned char const *in, unsigned char const *past, unsigned char *out) {
  __m128i const mask0 = _mm_set1_epi16((short)0x8000),
                mask1 = _mm_set1_epi8(0x0F),
                mul = _mm_set1_epi16(0x0011);
  __m128i       u, v, w, x;
  do {
    // Read input into low 8 bytes of u and v
    u = _mm_load_si128((__m128i const*)in);

    v = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(u, u);      // Expand each single byte to two bytes
    u = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(u, u);      // Do it again for v
    w = _mm_srli_epi16(u, 4);         // Copy the value into w and shift it right half a byte
    x = _mm_srli_epi16(v, 4);         // Do it again for v
    u = _mm_blendv_epi8(u, w, mask0); // Select odd bytes from w, and even bytes from v, giving the the desired value in the upper nibble of each byte
    v = _mm_blendv_epi8(v, x, mask0); // Do it again for v
    u = _mm_and_si128(u, mask1);      // Clear the all the upper nibbles
    v = _mm_and_si128(v, mask1);      // Do it again for v
    u = _mm_mullo_epi16(u, mul);      // Multiply each 16-bit value by 0x0011 to duplicate the lower nibble in the upper nibble of each byte
    v = _mm_mullo_epi16(v, mul);      // Do it again for v

    // Write output
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(out     ), u);
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(out + 16), v);
    in  += 16;
    out += 32;
  } while (in != past);
}

void ExpandSSE4Unroll(unsigned char const *in, unsigned char const *past, unsigned char *out) {
  __m128i const mask0  = _mm_set1_epi16((short)0x8000),
                mask1  = _mm_set1_epi8(0x0F),
                mul    = _mm_set1_epi16(0x0011);
  __m128i       u0, v0, w0, x0,
                u1, v1, w1, x1,
                u2, v2, w2, x2,
                u3, v3, w3, x3;
  do {
    // Read input into low 8 bytes of u and v
    u0 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i const*)(in     ));
    u1 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i const*)(in + 16));
    u2 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i const*)(in + 32));
    u3 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i const*)(in + 48));

    v0 = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(u0, u0);      // Expand each single byte to two bytes
    u0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(u0, u0);      // Do it again for v
    v1 = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(u1, u1);      // Do it again
    u1 = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(u1, u1);      // Again for u1
    v2 = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(u2, u2);      // Again for v1
    u2 = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(u2, u2);      // Again for u2
    v3 = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(u3, u3);      // Again for v2
    u3 = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(u3, u3);      // Again for u3
    w0 = _mm_srli_epi16(u0, 4);          // Copy the value into w and shift it right half a byte
    x0 = _mm_srli_epi16(v0, 4);          // Do it again for v
    w1 = _mm_srli_epi16(u1, 4);          // Again for u1
    x1 = _mm_srli_epi16(v1, 4);          // Again for v1
    w2 = _mm_srli_epi16(u2, 4);          // Again for u2
    x2 = _mm_srli_epi16(v2, 4);          // Again for v2
    w3 = _mm_srli_epi16(u3, 4);          // Again for u3
    x3 = _mm_srli_epi16(v3, 4);          // Again for v3
    u0 = _mm_blendv_epi8(u0, w0, mask0); // Select even bytes from w, and odd bytes from v, giving the the desired value in the upper nibble of each byte
    v0 = _mm_blendv_epi8(v0, x0, mask0); // Do it again for v
    u1 = _mm_blendv_epi8(u1, w1, mask0); // Again for u1
    v1 = _mm_blendv_epi8(v1, x1, mask0); // Again for v1
    u2 = _mm_blendv_epi8(u2, w2, mask0); // Again for u2
    v2 = _mm_blendv_epi8(v2, x2, mask0); // Again for v2
    u3 = _mm_blendv_epi8(u3, w3, mask0); // Again for u3
    v3 = _mm_blendv_epi8(v3, x3, mask0); // Again for v3
    u0 = _mm_and_si128(u0, mask1);       // Clear the all the upper nibbles
    v0 = _mm_and_si128(v0, mask1);       // Do it again for v
    u1 = _mm_and_si128(u1, mask1);       // Again for u1
    v1 = _mm_and_si128(v1, mask1);       // Again for v1
    u2 = _mm_and_si128(u2, mask1);       // Again for u2
    v2 = _mm_and_si128(v2, mask1);       // Again for v2
    u3 = _mm_and_si128(u3, mask1);       // Again for u3
    v3 = _mm_and_si128(v3, mask1);       // Again for v3
    u0 = _mm_mullo_epi16(u0, mul);       // Multiply each 16-bit value by 0x0011 to duplicate the lower nibble in the upper nibble of each byte
    v0 = _mm_mullo_epi16(v0, mul);       // Do it again for v
    u1 = _mm_mullo_epi16(u1, mul);       // Again for u1
    v1 = _mm_mullo_epi16(v1, mul);       // Again for v1
    u2 = _mm_mullo_epi16(u2, mul);       // Again for u2
    v2 = _mm_mullo_epi16(v2, mul);       // Again for v2
    u3 = _mm_mullo_epi16(u3, mul);       // Again for u3
    v3 = _mm_mullo_epi16(v3, mul);       // Again for v3

    // Write output
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(out      ), u0);
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(out +  16), v0);
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(out +  32), u1);
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(out +  48), v1);
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(out +  64), u2);
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(out +  80), v2);
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(out +  96), u3);
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(out + 112), v3);
    in  += 64;
    out += 128;
  } while (in != past);
}

void ExpandSSE2(unsigned char const *in, unsigned char const *past, unsigned char *out) {
  __m128i const mask = _mm_set1_epi16((short)0xF00F),
                mul0 = _mm_set1_epi16(0x0011),
                mul1 = _mm_set1_epi16(0x1000);
  __m128i       u, v;
  do {
    // Read input into low 8 bytes of u and v
    u = _mm_load_si128((__m128i const*)in);

    v = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(u, u);      // Expand each single byte to two bytes
    u = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(u, u);      // Do it again for v

    u = _mm_and_si128(u, mask);
    v = _mm_and_si128(v, mask);
    u = _mm_mullo_epi16(u, mul0);
    v = _mm_mullo_epi16(v, mul0);
    u = _mm_mulhi_epu16(u, mul1);     // This can also be done with a right shift of 4 bits, but this seems to mesure faster
    v = _mm_mulhi_epu16(v, mul1);
    u = _mm_mullo_epi16(u, mul0);
    v = _mm_mullo_epi16(v, mul0);

    // write output
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(out     ), u);
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(out + 16), v);
    in  += 16;
    out += 32;
  } while (in != past);
}

void ExpandSSE2Unroll(unsigned char const *in, unsigned char const *past, unsigned char *out) {
  __m128i const mask = _mm_set1_epi16((short)0xF00F),
                mul0 = _mm_set1_epi16(0x0011),
                mul1 = _mm_set1_epi16(0x1000);
  __m128i       u0, v0,
                u1, v1;
  do {
    // Read input into low 8 bytes of u and v
    u0 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i const*)(in     ));
    u1 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i const*)(in + 16));

    v0 = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(u0, u0);      // Expand each single byte to two bytes
    u0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(u0, u0);      // Do it again for v
    v1 = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(u1, u1);      // Do it again
    u1 = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(u1, u1);      // Again for u1

    u0 = _mm_and_si128(u0, mask);
    v0 = _mm_and_si128(v0, mask);
    u1 = _mm_and_si128(u1, mask);
    v1 = _mm_and_si128(v1, mask);

    u0 = _mm_mullo_epi16(u0, mul0);
    v0 = _mm_mullo_epi16(v0, mul0);
    u1 = _mm_mullo_epi16(u1, mul0);
    v1 = _mm_mullo_epi16(v1, mul0);

    u0 = _mm_mulhi_epu16(u0, mul1);
    v0 = _mm_mulhi_epu16(v0, mul1);
    u1 = _mm_mulhi_epu16(u1, mul1);
    v1 = _mm_mulhi_epu16(v1, mul1);

    u0 = _mm_mullo_epi16(u0, mul0);
    v0 = _mm_mullo_epi16(v0, mul0);
    u1 = _mm_mullo_epi16(u1, mul0);
    v1 = _mm_mullo_epi16(v1, mul0);

    // write output
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(out     ), u0);
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(out + 16), v0);
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(out + 32), u1);
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(out + 48), v1);

    in  += 32;
    out += 64;
  } while (in != past);
}

void ExpandAShellySSE4(unsigned char const *in, unsigned char const *past, unsigned char *out) {
  __m128i const zero      = _mm_setzero_si128(),
                v0F0F     = _mm_set1_epi32(0x0F0F),
                vF0F0     = _mm_set1_epi32(0xF0F0),
                v0101     = _mm_set1_epi32(0x0101),
                v1010     = _mm_set1_epi32(0x1010),
                v000F000F = _mm_set1_epi32(0x000F000F),
                v0F000F00 = _mm_set1_epi32(0x0F000F00),
                v0011 = _mm_set1_epi32(0x0011);
  __m128i       u, v, w, x;
  do {
    // Read in data
    u = _mm_load_si128((__m128i const*)in);
    v = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(u, zero);
    u = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(u, zero);

    // original source: ((((a & 0xF0F) * 0x101) & 0xF000F) + (((a & 0xF0F0) * 0x1010) & 0xF000F00)) * 0x11;
    w = _mm_and_si128(u, v0F0F);
    x = _mm_and_si128(v, v0F0F);
    u = _mm_and_si128(u, vF0F0);
    v = _mm_and_si128(v, vF0F0);
    w = _mm_mullo_epi32(w, v0101); // _mm_mullo_epi32 is what makes this require SSE4 instead of SSE2
    x = _mm_mullo_epi32(x, v0101);
    u = _mm_mullo_epi32(u, v1010);
    v = _mm_mullo_epi32(v, v1010);
    w = _mm_and_si128(w, v000F000F);
    x = _mm_and_si128(x, v000F000F);
    u = _mm_and_si128(u, v0F000F00);
    v = _mm_and_si128(v, v0F000F00);
    u = _mm_add_epi32(u, w);
    v = _mm_add_epi32(v, x);
    u = _mm_mullo_epi32(u, v0011);
    v = _mm_mullo_epi32(v, v0011);

    // write output
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(out     ), u);
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(out + 16), v);
    in  += 16;
    out += 32;
  } while (in != past);
}

int main() {
  unsigned char *const indat   = new unsigned char[DATA_SIZE_IN ],
                *const outdat0 = new unsigned char[DATA_SIZE_OUT],
                *const outdat1 = new unsigned char[DATA_SIZE_OUT],
                *      curout  = outdat0,
                *      lastout = outdat1,
                *      place;
  unsigned             start,
                       stop;

  place = indat + DATA_SIZE_IN - 1;
  do {
    *place = (unsigned char)rand();
  } while (place-- != indat);
  MakeLutLo();
  MakeLutHi();
  MakeLutLarge();

  for (unsigned testcount = 0; testcount < 1000; ++testcount) {
    // Solution posted by the asker
    start = clock();
    for (unsigned rerun = 0; rerun < RERUN_COUNT; ++rerun)
      ExpandOrig(indat, indat + DATA_SIZE_IN, curout);
    stop = clock();
    std::cout << "ExpandOrig:\t\t\t" << (((stop - start) / 1000) / 60) << ':' << (((stop - start) / 1000) % 60) << ":." << ((stop - start) % 1000) << std::endl;

    std::swap(curout, lastout);

    // Dmitry's small lookup table solution
    start = clock();
    for (unsigned rerun = 0; rerun < RERUN_COUNT; ++rerun)
      ExpandLookupSmall(indat, indat + DATA_SIZE_IN, curout);
    stop = clock();
    std::cout << "ExpandSmallLUT:\t\t\t" << (((stop - start) / 1000) / 60) << ':' << (((stop - start) / 1000) % 60) << ":." << ((stop - start) % 1000) << std::endl;

    std::swap(curout, lastout);
    if (memcmp(outdat0, outdat1, DATA_SIZE_OUT))
      std::cout << "INCORRECT OUTPUT" << std::endl;

    // Dmitry's small lookup table solution using only one lookup table
    start = clock();
    for (unsigned rerun = 0; rerun < RERUN_COUNT; ++rerun)
      ExpandLookupSmallOneLUT(indat, indat + DATA_SIZE_IN, curout);
    stop = clock();
    std::cout << "ExpandLookupSmallOneLUT:\t" << (((stop - start) / 1000) / 60) << ':' << (((stop - start) / 1000) % 60) << ":." << ((stop - start) % 1000) << std::endl;

    std::swap(curout, lastout);
    if (memcmp(outdat0, outdat1, DATA_SIZE_OUT))
      std::cout << "INCORRECT OUTPUT" << std::endl;

    // Large lookup table solution
    start = clock();
    for (unsigned rerun = 0; rerun < RERUN_COUNT; ++rerun)
      ExpandLookupLarge(indat, indat + DATA_SIZE_IN, curout);
    stop = clock();
    std::cout << "ExpandLookupLarge:\t\t" << (((stop - start) / 1000) / 60) << ':' << (((stop - start) / 1000) % 60) << ":." << ((stop - start) % 1000) << std::endl;

    std::swap(curout, lastout);
    if (memcmp(outdat0, outdat1, DATA_SIZE_OUT))
      std::cout << "INCORRECT OUTPUT" << std::endl;

    // AShelly's Interleave bits by Binary Magic Numbers solution
    start = clock();
    for (unsigned rerun = 0; rerun < RERUN_COUNT; ++rerun)
      ExpandAShelly(indat, indat + DATA_SIZE_IN, curout);
    stop = clock();
    std::cout << "ExpandAShelly:\t\t\t" << (((stop - start) / 1000) / 60) << ':' << (((stop - start) / 1000) % 60) << ":." << ((stop - start) % 1000) << std::endl;

    std::swap(curout, lastout);
    if (memcmp(outdat0, outdat1, DATA_SIZE_OUT))
      std::cout << "INCORRECT OUTPUT" << std::endl;

    // AShelly's Interleave bits by Binary Magic Numbers solution optimizing out an addition
    start = clock();
    for (unsigned rerun = 0; rerun < RERUN_COUNT; ++rerun)
      ExpandAShellyMulOp(indat, indat + DATA_SIZE_IN, curout);
    stop = clock();
    std::cout << "ExpandAShellyMulOp:\t\t" << (((stop - start) / 1000) / 60) << ':' << (((stop - start) / 1000) % 60) << ":." << ((stop - start) % 1000) << std::endl;

    std::swap(curout, lastout);
    if (memcmp(outdat0, outdat1, DATA_SIZE_OUT))
      std::cout << "INCORRECT OUTPUT" << std::endl;

    // My SSE4 solution
    start = clock();
    for (unsigned rerun = 0; rerun < RERUN_COUNT; ++rerun)
      ExpandSSE4(indat, indat + DATA_SIZE_IN, curout);
    stop = clock();
    std::cout << "ExpandSSE4:\t\t\t" << (((stop - start) / 1000) / 60) << ':' << (((stop - start) / 1000) % 60) << ":." << ((stop - start) % 1000) << std::endl;

    std::swap(curout, lastout);
    if (memcmp(outdat0, outdat1, DATA_SIZE_OUT))
      std::cout << "INCORRECT OUTPUT" << std::endl;

    // My SSE4 solution unrolled
    start = clock();
    for (unsigned rerun = 0; rerun < RERUN_COUNT; ++rerun)
      ExpandSSE4Unroll(indat, indat + DATA_SIZE_IN, curout);
    stop = clock();
    std::cout << "ExpandSSE4Unroll:\t\t" << (((stop - start) / 1000) / 60) << ':' << (((stop - start) / 1000) % 60) << ":." << ((stop - start) % 1000) << std::endl;

    std::swap(curout, lastout);
    if (memcmp(outdat0, outdat1, DATA_SIZE_OUT))
      std::cout << "INCORRECT OUTPUT" << std::endl;

    // My SSE2 solution
    start = clock();
    for (unsigned rerun = 0; rerun < RERUN_COUNT; ++rerun)
      ExpandSSE2(indat, indat + DATA_SIZE_IN, curout);
    stop = clock();
    std::cout << "ExpandSSE2:\t\t\t" << (((stop - start) / 1000) / 60) << ':' << (((stop - start) / 1000) % 60) << ":." << ((stop - start) % 1000) << std::endl;

    std::swap(curout, lastout);
    if (memcmp(outdat0, outdat1, DATA_SIZE_OUT))
      std::cout << "INCORRECT OUTPUT" << std::endl;

    // My SSE2 solution unrolled
    start = clock();
    for (unsigned rerun = 0; rerun < RERUN_COUNT; ++rerun)
      ExpandSSE2Unroll(indat, indat + DATA_SIZE_IN, curout);
    stop = clock();
    std::cout << "ExpandSSE2Unroll:\t\t" << (((stop - start) / 1000) / 60) << ':' << (((stop - start) / 1000) % 60) << ":." << ((stop - start) % 1000) << std::endl;

    std::swap(curout, lastout);
    if (memcmp(outdat0, outdat1, DATA_SIZE_OUT))
      std::cout << "INCORRECT OUTPUT" << std::endl;

    // AShelly's Interleave bits by Binary Magic Numbers solution implemented using SSE2
    start = clock();
    for (unsigned rerun = 0; rerun < RERUN_COUNT; ++rerun)
      ExpandAShellySSE4(indat, indat + DATA_SIZE_IN, curout);
    stop = clock();
    std::cout << "ExpandAShellySSE4:\t\t" << (((stop - start) / 1000) / 60) << ':' << (((stop - start) / 1000) % 60) << ":." << ((stop - start) % 1000) << std::endl;

    std::swap(curout, lastout);
    if (memcmp(outdat0, outdat1, DATA_SIZE_OUT))
      std::cout << "INCORRECT OUTPUT" << std::endl;
  }

  delete[] indat;
  delete[] outdat0;
  delete[] outdat1;
  return 0;
}
```

**NOTE:**

I had an SSE4 implementation here initially. I found a way to implement this using SSE2, which is better because it will run on more platforms. The SSE2 implementation is also faster. So, the solution presented at the top is now the SSE2 implementation and not the SSE4 one. The SSE4 implementation can still be seen in the performance tests or in the edit history.

Comment: Nice Job. Thanks for doing the tests.  If I've learned one thing from them its this:  I don't want to write SSE code unless I absolutely have to have that last iota of performance :)  It is sure not easy to read.

Comment: @AShelly: Nobody does, especially if portability is a concern. There are a wide range of SIMD instruction sets... SSE is only valid in the x86 world. You have to deal with AltiVec (VMX) on PPC and NEON on ARM to name a few. Interfacing directly with instruction set extensions is ugly on any architecture though ;)

Comment: @AShelly Thank you. The SSE isn't so bad once you start to memorize what some of the operations are and their naming conventions. I only really started using it a few months back. It also helps when working with the ordering of vector elements becomes more second nature. The small LUT was a pretty fast solution too. There is a vectorized lookup, _mm_i32gather_epi32, which will do 4 lookups in parallel (AVX is the successor to SSE). It would be interesting to see how a solution involving this performs. However it requires AVX2 instructions, and I don't yet have access to a processor that new.

Comment: I ran your performance test on my system (a later Core 2, 64-bit linux, gcc 4.8.1 using -O3 -march=native).  While your SSE4 code was fastest, many of the bit-manipulation solutions were almost as fast (within a few percent)... apparently gcc does a reasonable job of vectorizing the code on it's own when the relevant features and optimizations are enabled.

Comment: @Dmitri It's nice to know compilers are getting better at auto-vectorization. I would however imagine it's difficult for the compiler to determine what your algorithm is actually trying to accomplish on a high level from the relatively limited set of operations provided through C++ in order to utilize shuffle/blend/unpack/ect operations in an overall more efficient way. Rather, I would guess it will try to mimic the C++ code in a vectorized manner, similarly to the SSE implementation I included of AShelly's solution, but that is just a guess.

Comment: I'm surprised that the lookup table was half as fast as the SSE2 solution.  Any thoughts on why that is?

Comment: @Eric J. I’m actually surprised the look up table method was as fast as it was. The straight forward look-up table method was slow because 256kb exceeds the L1 cache. The small look-up table is so fast because it all fits in L1 cache, 2k for both tables. But it needs a SHIFT, an OR, and an AND, per color value to use the smaller table, that’s an extra 3 operations per color in addition to the look-ups. There are also extra operations around reading in the input (the way I did it was the fastest I could find) that are unnecessary for the SSE2 implementation.

Comment: @Eric J. So what it really comes down to is that the assembly will contain this, if it is a direct translation of how the source is written: the SSE2 impl will contain 1 read, 2 writes, 1 move, 10 operations, 2 pointer increments, in order to process 8 color values; so that’s around 2 instructions per color value. And the LUT impl will contain 5 reads, 2 writes, 3 moves, 8 operations, 2 pointer increments, in order to process 2 colors.

Comment: @EricJ. When I tested, the lookup tables were almost as fast as the SSE code... but I was also using a different compiler, OS, CPU, etc.  Also, the larger table performs better with actual image data because there are fewer cache misses (adjacent pixels tend to hit the same region of the table).

Comment: @Eric J. This scales up to: 20 reads, 8 writes, 12 moves, 32 operations, 8 pointer increments, in order to process 8 colors; so that’s around 10 instructions per color value. Of course however some of these operations will happen in parallel on superscalar architecture, and the compiler may optimize some of this eliminating moves and unrolling loops. So, as a rough tally, it makes a lot of sense why the SSE2 impl would be faster.

Comment: @Eric J. All that said, you could make all of this even faster using AVX instructions (AVX is SSE’s successor) either by extending the implementation here, using 256-bit registers instead of 128-bit registers. Or by using the very powerful intrinsic _mm256_i32gather_epi32, which performs gathered loads, to implement a vectorized look-up table.

Comment: @Dmitry Since you've ran the test I shaved a couple operations from the SSE4 version. And then found an SSE2 version with the same number of operations, maybe minus a move or two, which also ran slightly faster for me than the SSE4 version. I can't reference anything, but it seems like I read somewhere that some of the SSS3/SSE4 operations were slower (more cycles) on earlier supporting hardware. I'd be curious of how the SSE2 version performs on your Core2, but I'd also certainly understand if you have better things to do.

Comment: @Apriori I already reran the tests and included your SSE2 version, and updated my answer with the new results.

Comment: @Dmitry Ah, sorry I hadn't looked at your post again, thank you for testing all that and posting the data. I wonder if it's possible there is a memory bottleneck, my machine is pretty overclocked, ram an all.  I should have a chance tomorrow to run this on a different machine, but practically the same everything else (compiler/proc/OS).

Comment: I found a somewhat less beefy laptop to run the exe on. The results are in roughly the same proportions as I've posted above. This means that it's not a memory bottleneck.

Answer (score 21):

I'm not sure what the *most efficient* way would be, but this is a little shorter:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  unsigned x = 0x1234;

  x = (x << 8) | x;
  x = ((x & 0x00f000f0) << 4) | (x & 0x000f000f);
  x = (x << 4) | x;

  printf("0x1234 -> 0x%08x\n",x);

  return 0;
}
```

---

If you need to do this repeatedly and very quickly, as suggested in your edit, you could consider generating a lookup table and using that instead.  The following function dynamically allocates and initializes such a table:

```
unsigned *makeLookupTable(void)
{
  unsigned *tbl = malloc(sizeof(unsigned) * 65536);
  if (!tbl) return NULL;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 65536; i++) {
    unsigned x = i;
    x |= (x << 8);
    x = ((x & 0x00f000f0) << 4) | (x & 0x000f000f);
    x |= (x << 4);

    /* Uncomment next line to invert the high byte as mentioned in the edit. */
    /* x = x ^ 0xff000000; */

    tbl[i] = x;
  }
  return tbl;
}
```

After that each conversion is just something like:

```
result = lookuptable[input];
```

..or maybe:

```
result = lookuptable[input & 0xffff];
```

---

Or a smaller, more cache-friendly lookup table (or pair) could be used with one lookup each for the high and low bytes (as noted by @LưuVĩnhPhúc in the comments).  In that case, table generation code might be:

```
unsigned *makeLookupTableLow(void)
{
  unsigned *tbl = malloc(sizeof(unsigned) * 256);
  if (!tbl) return NULL;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    unsigned x = i;
    x = ((x & 0xf0) << 4) | (x & 0x0f);
    x |= (x << 4);
    tbl[i] = x;
  }
  return tbl;
}
```

...and an optional second table:

```
unsigned *makeLookupTableHigh(void)
{
  unsigned *tbl = malloc(sizeof(unsigned) * 256);
  if (!tbl) return NULL;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    unsigned x = i;
    x = ((x & 0xf0) << 20) | ((x & 0x0f) << 16);
    x |= (x << 4);

    /* uncomment next line to invert high byte */
    /* x = x ^ 0xff000000; */

    tbl[i] = x;
  }
  return tbl;
}
```

...and to convert a value with two tables:

```
result = hightable[input >> 8] | lowtable[input & 0xff];
```

...or with one (just the low table above):

```
result = (lowtable[input >> 8] << 16) | lowtable[input & 0xff];
result ^= 0xff000000; /* to invert high byte */
```

If the upper part of the value (alpha?) doesn't change much, even the single large table might perform well since consecutive lookups would be closer together in the table.

---

I took the performance test code @Apriori posted, made some adjustments, and added tests for the other responses that he hadn't included originally... then compiled three versions of it with different settings.  One is 64-bit code with SSE4.1 enabled, where the compiler can make use of SSE for optimizations... and then two 32-bit versions, one with SSE and one without.  Although all three were run on the same fairly recent processor, the results show how the optimal solution can change depending on the processor features:

```
                           64b SSE4.1  32b SSE4.1  32b no SSE
-------------------------- ----------  ----------  ----------
ExpandOrig           time:  3.502 s     3.501 s     6.260 s
ExpandLookupSmall    time:  3.530 s     3.997 s     3.996 s
ExpandLookupLarge    time:  3.434 s     3.419 s     3.427 s
ExpandIsalamon       time:  3.654 s     3.673 s     8.870 s
ExpandIsalamonOpt    time:  3.784 s     3.720 s     8.719 s
ExpandChronoKitsune  time:  3.658 s     3.463 s     6.546 s
ExpandEvgenyKluev    time:  6.790 s     7.697 s    13.383 s
ExpandIammilind      time:  3.485 s     3.498 s     6.436 s
ExpandDmitri         time:  3.457 s     3.477 s     5.461 s
ExpandNitish712      time:  3.574 s     3.800 s     6.789 s
ExpandAdamLiss       time:  3.673 s     5.680 s     6.969 s
ExpandAShelly        time:  3.524 s     4.295 s     5.867 s
ExpandAShellyMulOp   time:  3.527 s     4.295 s     5.852 s
ExpandSSE4           time:  3.428 s
ExpandSSE4Unroll     time:  3.333 s
ExpandSSE2           time:  3.392 s
ExpandSSE2Unroll     time:  3.318 s
ExpandAShellySSE4    time:  3.392 s
```

The executables were compiled on 64-bit Linux with gcc 4.8.1, using `-m64 -O3 -march=core2 -msse4.1`, `-m32 -O3 -march=core2 -msse4.1` and `-m32 -O3 -march=core2 -mno-sse` respectively.  @Apriori's SSE tests were omitted for the 32-bit builds (crashed on 32-bit with SSE enabled, and obviously won't work with SSE disabled).

Among the adjustments made was to use actual image data instead of random values (photos of objects with transparent backgrounds), which greatly improved the performance of the large lookup table but made little difference for the others.

Essentially, the lookup tables win by a landslide when SSE is unnavailable (or unused)... and the manually coded SSE solutions win otherwise.  However, it's also noteworthy that when the compiler could use SSE for optimizations, most of the bit manipulation solutions were almost as fast as the manually coded SSE -- still slower, but only marginally.

Comment: Anything involving malloc will be horribly inefficient, in comparison to what the OP already got.

Comment: @Lundin It's a one-time malloc to setup the table, it's not part of the conversions.

Comment: So? It has to be done in runtime so it makes the program much slower. For efficiency reasons, you should use a `static const` lookup table, if possible.

Comment: @Lundin It only has to be done *once* at runtime though... it'll just take a fraction of a second at program start.  A static const table would work too, but you'd want to write a program to generate the source code given the size of the table.

Comment: Just 256 entry lookup table is enough. You can lookup the low and high byte seperately. Too large table may not fit in cache and performance may be worse

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Good point... and it'd work better for smaller cache sizes that way.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen No, `x = (x << 8) | x;` is correct.  Try working out an example by hand..

Comment: +1 for the elegant, simple lookup table solution that doesn't try to outclever itself, especially in production code. It may not win the geek popularity contest but I'd rather see this in my coworkers' code than the other solutions.

Comment: Thank you for running this on on different hardware/system, and adding the other solutions. Out of curiosity, is the image data hard coded in the cpp? Or is it somewhere the compiler/optimizer can't possibly know what is in the buffer at compile time.

Comment: @Apriori The image data is loaded from a separate file before the tests run.

Answer (score 12):

Here's another attempt, using eight operations:

```
b = (((c & 0x0F0F) * 0x0101) & 0x00F000F) + 
    (((c & 0xF0F0) * 0x1010) & 0xF000F00);
b += b * 0x10;

printf("%x\n",b); //Shows '0x11223344'
```

---

*Note, this post originally contained quite different code, based on [Interleave bits by Binary Magic Numbers](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#InterleaveBMN) from Sean Anderson's bithacks page.  But that wasn't quite what the OP was asking. so it has ben removed. The majority of the comments below refer to that [missing version](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21771366/revisions).

Comment: That's some seriously ugly code there. No matter how efficient this turns out to be, it looks like premature optimization. I'd seriously consider using less efficient code for the sake of readability, maintenance and bug free code.

Comment: @Lundin the codes overthere are already debugged, just use and if there is any problem, it's in your code. You can always leave a comment in the code to describe what the function do and where did you take it from

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Indeed any bug will be in my code. And how do you propose that I smoothly debug said code, if my program is one big goo of magic numbers?

Comment: I'd go for this, but do it by coding the text in the page referred to as a `#define`, so the compiler does the optimisation. That way it will be moderately readable.

Comment: By the way, if this works I think it's super cool. However, I would expect 0x1234 to become 0x11223344 as the asker suggests, but when I plug 0x1234 into this code I get 0x0000303C. Perhaps some of the precedence in the code posted is off somewhere or there was some other minor oversight?

Comment: The proposed code would duplicate **single bits** of 8-bit value. While OP asks for duplicating **4-bit nibbles** of 16-bit value.

Comment: You are absolutely right @EvgenyKluev.  This won't work.

Comment: Read my post, it ISNT always simply about operations.  Yours may indeed be optimal, but we should be careful as the OP is indeed asking for the most optimal in terms of time, not operations.

Comment: You're absolutely right. None of these suggestions mean anything without profiling a typical use case.  But at least now there are several options to choose from.

Comment: This code will also vectorize very well. Everything you're doing here can be done with SSE2 (My solution requires SSE4.1). In addition it has more independent calculations than my solution, so it's likely more of the instructions will execute in parallel. I think there's a good chance a vectorized version of your approach would be faster than my own vectorized code. However, there IS only one way to know.

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to add this link into the answer pool because I think it is extremely important when talking about optimization, to remember the hardware we are running on, as well as the technologies compiling our code for said platform.

Blog post *[Playing with the CPU pipeline](http://lolengine.net/blog/2011/9/17/playing-with-the-cpu-pipeline)*  is about looking into optimizing a set of code for the CPU pipelining. It actually shows an example of where he tries to simplify the math down to the fewest actual mathematical operations, yet it was FAR from the most optimal solution in terms of time. I have seen a couple of answers here speaking to that effect, and they may be correct, they may not. The only way to know is to actually measure the time from start to finish of your particular snippet of code, in comparison to others. Read this blog; it is EXTREMELY interesting.

I think I should mention that I am in this particular case not going to put ANY code up here unless I have truly tried multiple attempts, and actually gotten on that is particularly faster through multiple tries.

Comment: Although I agree with you about the need for profiling, this answer is not really an answer.

Comment: @AShelly - I think everybody else here is giving answers, and they don't KNOW.  The point I am trying to potentially make is that without working it for your particular architecture, you actually wont KNOW.  Indeed just because it is x86 doesn't mean it will be the same either.  An AMD may be different than an intel, indeed an i7 may be different than a core 2.  Simply asking what is the fastest, is a much more difficult answer than the code itself.

Answer (score 5):

I think that the lookup table approach suggested by [Dimitri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/929459/dmitri) is a good choice, but I suggest to go one step further and generate the table in compile time; doing the work at compile time will obviously lessen the execution time.

First, we create a compile-time value, using any of the suggested methods:

```
constexpr unsigned int transform1(unsigned int x)
{
  return ((x << 8) | x);
}

constexpr unsigned int transform2(unsigned int x)
{
  return (((x & 0x00f000f0) << 4) | (x & 0x000f000f));
}

constexpr unsigned int transform3(unsigned int x)
{
  return ((x << 4) | x);
}

constexpr unsigned int transform(unsigned int x)
{
  return transform3(transform2(transform1(x)));
}

// Dimitri version, using constexprs
template <unsigned int argb> struct aarrggbb_dimitri
{
  static const unsigned int value = transform(argb);
};

// Adam Liss version
template <unsigned int argb> struct aarrggbb_adamLiss
{
  static const unsigned int value =
    (argb & 0xf000) * 0x11000 +
    (argb & 0x0f00) * 0x01100 +
    (argb & 0x00f0) * 0x00110 +
    (argb & 0x000f) * 0x00011;
};
```

And then, we create the compile-time lookup table with whatever method we have available, I'll wish to use the C++14 [integer sequence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) but I don't know which compiler will the OP be using. So another possible approach would be to use a pretty ugly macro:

```
#define EXPAND16(x) aarrggbb<x + 0>::value, \
aarrggbb<x + 1>::value, \
aarrggbb<x + 2>::value, \
aarrggbb<x + 3>::value, \
aarrggbb<x + 4>::value, \
aarrggbb<x + 5>::value, \
aarrggbb<x + 6>::value, \
... and so on

#define EXPAND EXPAND16(0), \
EXPAND16(0x10), \
EXPAND16(0x20), \
EXPAND16(0x30), \
EXPAND16(0x40), \
... and so on

... and so on
```

See [demo here](http://ideone.com/LqkN6h).

PS: The [Adam Liss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29157/adam-liss) approach could be used without C++11.

Answer (score 5):

If multiplication is cheap and 64-bit arithmetics is available, you could use this code:

```
uint64_t x = 0x1234;
x *= 0x0001000100010001ull;
x &= 0xF0000F0000F0000Full;
x *= 0x0000001001001001ull;
x &= 0xF0F0F0F000000000ull;
x = (x >> 36) * 0x11;
std::cout << std::hex << x << '\n';
```

In fact, it uses the same idea as the original attempt by AShelly.

Answer (score 4):

This works and may be easier to understand, but bit manipulations are so cheap that I wouldn't worry much about efficiency.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main() {
  unsigned int c = 0x1234, b;

  b = (c & 0xf000) * 0x11000 + (c & 0x0f00) * 0x01100 +
      (c & 0x00f0) * 0x00110 + (c & 0x000f) * 0x00011;

  printf("%x -> %x\n", c, b);
}
```

Comment: I believe the multiplication operations are expensive in the most architectures. Additionally, it may have to use a math processor.

Comment: That's not nearly as true as it used to be.

Comment: Try this: write a quick C program that multiplies a number by 0x11. Write another that shifts it left 4 bits and adds the result to the original. Compile them both to assembly and compare the results.  "Belief" isn't nearly as important as verification, _especially_ when it comes to modern compiler optimization.

Comment: @AdamLiss I do want to add here that I believe heavily in verification over belief, but it is a fairly well known fact that multiplication is indeed slower than addition no matter whether it is floating point or integer.  I found it here http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/299987, that in a core 2 it is still 3 times slower than addition or bitwise operations.  I think Adam is saying that in this case, the compiler will essentially optimize the multiplications to either an add or some bitwise operator.  This code then can indeed be fast and easy to read.

Comment: The point is that, depending on the multiplicands, the compiler may not generate multiply instructions at all. I spent quite a while as a new programmer trying to understand the assembly code that the compiler generated for the integer multiplication `n *= 10`. Then I realized it was smart enough to know that `n * 10` = `n * (2 + 8)` = `(n << 1) + (n << 3)` and it preferred the more-efficient shifts and adds to the simpler but more expensive multiplication. I'd be amazed if a compiler _didn't_ implement multiplication by `3 * 2^n`, which is `0x11 << n`, as shifts and adds.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that, you want to always convert `0xWXYZ` to `0xWWXXYYZZ`, I believe that below solution would be little faster than the one you suggested:

```
unsigned int c = 0x1234;     
unsigned int b = (c & 0xf) | ((c & 0xf0) << 4) |
                 ((c & 0xf00) << 8) | ((c & 0xf000) << 12);
b |= (b << 4);
```

Notice that, **one `&`(`and`) operation is saved** from your solution. :-)
[Demo](http://ideone.com/ZZXozy).

Answer (score 3):

Another way is:

```
DWORD OrVal(DWORD & nible_pos, DWORD input_val, DWORD temp_val, int shift)
{
    if (nible_pos==0)
        nible_pos = 0x0000000F;
    else
        nible_pos = nible_pos << 4;
    DWORD nible = input_val & nible_pos;
    temp_val |= (nible << shift);
    temp_val |= (nible << (shift + 4));
    return temp_val;
}

DWORD Converter2(DWORD input_val)
{
    DWORD nible_pos = 0x00000000;
    DWORD temp_val = 0x00000000;
    temp_val = OrVal(nible_pos, input_val, temp_val, 0);
    temp_val = OrVal(nible_pos, input_val, temp_val, 4);
    temp_val = OrVal(nible_pos, input_val, temp_val, 8);
    temp_val = OrVal(nible_pos, input_val, temp_val, 12);
    return temp_val;
}

DWORD val2 = Converter2(0x1234);
```

---

An optimized version (3 times faster):

```
DWORD Converter3(DWORD input_val)
{
    DWORD nible_pos = 0;
    DWORD temp_val = 0;
    int shift = 0;
    DWORD bit_nible[4] = { 0x000F, 0x000F0, 0x0F00, 0xF000 };

    for ( ; shift < 16; shift+=4 )
    {
        if (nible_pos==0)
            nible_pos = 0x0000000F;
        else
            nible_pos = nible_pos << 4;
        DWORD nible = input_val & nible_pos;
        temp_val |= (nible << shift);
        temp_val |= (nible << (shift + 4));
    }

    return temp_val;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this could be more simpler & efficient.

```
unsigned int g = 0x1234;
unsigned int ans = 0;

ans = ( ( g & 0xf000 ) << 16) + ( (g & 0xf00 ) << 12)
    + ( ( g&0xf0 ) << 8) + ( ( g&0xf ) << 4);

ans  = ( ans | ans>>4 );

printf("%p -> %p\n", g, ans);
```

Comment: This won't be efficient. You are using same number of `|` (or `+`), `<<` (or `>>`) as the earlier solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
unsigned long transform(unsigned long n)
{

    /* n: 00AR
     *    00GB
     */
    n = ((n & 0xff00) << 8) | (n & 0x00ff);

    /* n: 0AR0
     *    0GB0
     */
    n <<= 4;

    /* n: AAR0
     *    GGB0
     */
    n |= (n & 0x0f000f00L) << 4;

    /* n: AARR
     *    GGBB
     */
    n |= (n & 0x00f000f0L) >> 4;

    return n;
}
```

The alpha and red components are shifted into the higher 2 bytes where they belong, and the result is then shifted left by 4 bits, resulting in every component being exactly where it needs to be.

With a form of 0AR0 0GB0, a bit mask and left-shift combination is OR'ed with the current value. This copies the A and G components to the position just left of them. The same thing is done for the R and B components, except in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to do this for [OpenGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL), I suggest you to use a `glTexImageXD` function with `type` parameter set to `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4`. Your OpenGL driver should do the rest. And about the transparency inversion you can always manipulate blending via the `glBlendFunc` and `glBlendEquation` functions.

Comment: This should be marked as "Accepted answer" since this is what I need, but original formulation of a question was about numbers.

Answer (score -3):

While others operate on hard-core optimization...

Take this as your best bet:

```
std::string toAARRGGBB(const std::string &argb)
{
    std::string ret("0x");

    int start = 2; //"0x####";
                   // ^^ skipped

    for (int i = start;i < argb.length(); ++i)
    {
        ret += argb[i];
        ret += argb[i];
    }
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    std::string argb = toAARRGGBB("0xACED"); //!!!
}
```

*Haha*

Comment: The question is not to convert the number to a string - it is to change one number to a different number by duplicating the nibbles. I think you completely missed the point with your answer.

Comment: @mr5 as we love and know him ♥